# How can I reverse an array in JavaScript without using libraries?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am saving some data in order using `array`s, and I want to add a function that the user can reverse the list. I can't think of any possible method, so if anybody knows how, please help.

Comment: @jbabey "try google next time?"  Stackoverflow is not a place for rudeness.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

Javascript has a `reverse()` method that you can call in an array

```
var a = [3,5,7,8];
a.reverse(); // 8 7 5 3
```

Not sure if that's what you mean by 'libraries you can't use', I'm guessing something to do with practice. If that's the case, you can implement your own version of `.reverse()`

```
function reverseArr(input) {
    var ret = new Array;
    for(var i = input.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        ret.push(input[i]);
    }
    return ret;
}

var a = [3,5,7,8]
var b = reverseArr(a);
```

Do note that the built-in `.reverse()` method operates on the original array, thus you don't need to reassign `a`.

Comment: use [...arr].reverse() for undestructive reversing

Comment: `const b = a.toReversed();` returns a new array with the original in tact

Answer (score 62):

> [`Array.prototype.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) is all you need to do this work. See [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse#Browser_compatibility).

```js
var myArray = [20, 40, 80, 100];
var revMyArr = [].concat(myArray).reverse();
console.log(revMyArr);
// [100, 80, 40, 20]
```

Comment: nice, non-destructive

Comment: It should be noted that `concat` copies object references into the new array. Both the original and new array refer to the same object...

Answer (score 31):

Heres a functional way to do it.

```
const array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,"taco"];

function reverse(array){
  return array.map((item,idx) => array[array.length-1-idx])
}
```

Comment: Great and short solution if u don't want to change orig array!

Comment: This is great if you are writing a pure function or don't want to mutate the original array for any other reason.

Answer (score 24):

**20 bytes**

```
let reverse=a=>[...a].map(a.pop,a)
```

Comment: Could someone possibly explain this one for me?

Comment: @user169320 `[...a]` clones the array, `.map(a.pop, a)` pops the array (returns the last element of the array) and push it to a new array, which results in a reversed array.

Comment: ...and the 2nd argument to `map` makes sure that `pop` is executed with `a` as `this`, like as if you would have done `a.pop()`

Comment: @trincot Why do we have to execute `pop` with `a` as `this`? Could you explain a bit further?

Comment: When you pass on a function reference (so without executing it), which is later used for execution, then that function reference has *no trace at all* of the object you want to have it executed on: it is just a plain function. In the above code you might as well have put `[].pop` instead of `a.pop`: it would be *exactly* the same function. When the implementation of `map` executes that function, it does not know on which array it should be executed. And if you don't tell that, it will fail. The second argument to `map` gives the necessary info to `map`.

Comment: is it CodeGolf ?

Comment: Quite clever but bear in mind that this will mutate your original array making it empty (use a deep-freeze before, maybe)

Comment: what is the purpose of this method, if it mutates the original one and existing `reverse` method is shorter and more clear? The correct solution, whithout mutating of the original array is offered by @parag patel: `a.map(a.pop,[...a]); `

Answer (score 20):

```
const original = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const reversed = [...original].reverse(); // 4 3 2 1
```

Concise and leaves the original unchanged. Careful with object arrays, as the new array will still reference the same objects.

Comment: very useful , you are fade out my issues on reverse state

Comment: Just lost half a day due to not realizing this was an in-place operation. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 12):

```
reveresed = [...array].reverse()
```

Answer (score 10):

The shortest reverse method I've seen is this one:

```
let reverse = a=>a.sort(a=>1)
```

Comment: Doesn’t this depend on how the sorting is implemented? Since the comparing function isn’t consistent (i.e. it always returns 1) the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Actually I was surprised to see it work the way it did.
`[1,2,3,4].sort(a=>1)` returns the correct answer for example.
The idea is that it closely tied to how the sort method can take a sorting algorithm and since it does it one by one, it's always swaps.

Comment: The problem with this is that it might not reverse the array with different interpreters.

Comment: I'm not suggesting this as a good practice, just thought it's an interesting, unconventional take on a well known operation.

Answer (score 8):

This is what you want:

```
array.reverse();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Pp5e9/)

Comment: Note that array.reverse() will change the order of elements on the original array.

Answer (score 7):

two ways:

1. counter loop

   ```
   function reverseArray(a) { 
        var rA = []
        for (var i = a.length; i > 0; i--) {
            rA.push(a[i - 1])
        } 

        return rA;
     }
   ```
2. Using .reverse()

   ```
    function reverseArray(a) {  
        return a.reverse()  
     }
   ```

Answer (score 6):

## 53 bytes

```
function reverse(a){
    for(i=0,j=a.length-1;i<j;)a[i]=a[j]+(a[j--]=a[i++],0)
}
```

Just for fun, here's an alternative implementation that is faster than the native `.reverse` method.

Comment: I always look for that diamond in the rough where the solution is simple, compatible, and concise.  You won this question for me, in this case.  May you please explain it in detail?

Answer (score 6):

You can do

```
var yourArray = ["first", "second", "third", "...", "etc"]
var reverseArray = yourArray.slice().reverse()

console.log(reverseArray)
```

You will get

```
["etc", "...", "third", "second", "first"]
```

Comment: A good non-destructive solution. Note that `slice` does a shallow copy.

Answer (score 6):

**

### Shortest reverse array method without using reverse method:

**

```
 var a = [0, 1, 4, 1, 3, 9, 3, 7, 8544, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3];

 a.map(a.pop,[...a]); 
// returns [3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 8544, 7, 3, 9, 3, 1, 4, 1, 0]
```

a.pop method takes an last element off and puts upfront with spread operator ()

MDN links for reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop

Comment: Same as Torkel Velure 's answer [...a].map(a.pop,a)

Answer (score 5):

I've made some test of solutions that not only reverse array but also makes its copy. Here is test code. The `reverse2` method is the fastest one in Chrome but in Firefox the `reverse` method is the fastest.

```
var array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

var reverse1 = function() {
  var reversed = array.slice().reverse();
};

var reverse2 = function() {
  var reversed = [];
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    reversed.push(array[i]);
  }
};

var reverse3 = function() {
  var reversed = [];
  array.forEach(function(v) {
    reversed.unshift(v);
  });
};

console.time('reverse1');
for (var x = 0; x < 1000000; x++) {
  reverse1();
}
console.timeEnd('reverse1'); // Around 184ms on my computer in Chrome

console.time('reverse2');
for (var x = 0; x < 1000000; x++) {
  reverse2();
}
console.timeEnd('reverse2'); // Around 78ms on my computer in Chrome

console.time('reverse3');
for (var x = 0; x < 1000000; x++) {
  reverse3();
}
console.timeEnd('reverse3'); // Around 1114ms on my computer in Chrome
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a version which does not require temp array.

```
function inplaceReverse(arr) {
  var i = 0;
  while (i < arr.length - 1) {
    arr.splice(i, 0, arr.pop());
    i++;
  }
  return arr;
}

// Useage:
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(inplaceReverse(arr)); // [3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Doesn’t require a temp array, just Θ(n²) time. This should be done with single swaps.

Answer (score 4):

```
> var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
> arr.reverse();
  [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
array.reverse()
```

Above will reverse your array but modifying the original.
If you don't want to modify the original array then you can do this:

```
var arrayOne = [1,2,3,4,5];

var reverse = function(array){
    var arrayOne = array
    var array2 = [];

    for (var i = arrayOne.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
      array2.push(arrayOne[i])
    } 
    return array2
}

reverse(arrayOne)
```

Comment: The first example is not true. `arrayTwo` has a reference to the `arrayOne` so both arrays will be reversed.

Comment: You're right- thanks! I removed the first example so this is now correct :)

Answer (score 4):

```
function reverseArray(arr) {
    let reversed = [];
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
    reversed.push((arr[arr.length-1-i]))
    }
  return reversed;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As others mentioned, you can use `.reverse()` on the array object.

However if you care about **preserving the original object**, you may use `reduce` instead:

```
const original = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const reversed = original.reduce( (a, b) => [b].concat(a) );
//                                           ^
//                                           |
//                                           +-- prepend b to previous accumulation

// original: ['a', 'b', 'c'];
// reversed: ['c', 'b', 'a'];
```

Answer (score 4):

Using .pop() method and while loop.

```
var original = [1,2,3,4];
var reverse = [];
while(original.length){
    reverse.push(original.pop());
}
```

Output: [4,3,2,1]

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what is meant by libraries, but here are the best ways I can think of:

```
// return a new array with .map()
const ReverseArray1 = (array) => {
    let len = array.length - 1;

    return array.map(() => array[len--]);
}

console.log(ReverseArray1([1,2,3,4,5])) //[5,4,3,2,1]

// initialize and return a new array
const ReverseArray2 = (array) => {
    const newArray = [];
    let len = array.length;

    while (len--) {
        newArray.push(array[len]);
    }

    return newArray;
}

console.log(ReverseArray2([1,2,3,4,5]))//[5,4,3,2,1]

// use swapping and return original array
const ReverseArray3 = (array) => {
    let i = 0;
    let j = array.length - 1;

    while (i < j) {
        const swap = array[i];
        array[i++] = array[j];
        array[j--] = swap;
    }

    return array;
}
console.log(ReverseArray3([1,2,3,4,5]))//[5,4,3,2,1]

// use .pop() and .length
const ReverseArray4 = (array) => {
    const newArray = [];

    while (array.length) {
        newArray.push(array.pop());
    }

    return newArray;
}
console.log(ReverseArray4([1,2,3,4,5]))//[5,4,3,2,1]
```

Answer (score 3):

Pure functions to reverse an array using functional programming:

```
var a = [3,5,7,8];

// ES2015
function immutableReverse(arr) {
  return [ ...a ].reverse();
}

// ES5
function immutableReverse(arr) {
  return a.concat().reverse()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It can also be achieved using map method.

```
[1, 2, 3].map((value, index, arr) => arr[arr.length - index - 1])); // [3, 2, 1]
```

Or using reduce (little longer approach)

```
[1, 2, 3].reduce((acc, curr, index, arr) => {
    acc[arr.length - index - 1] = curr;
    return acc;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 3):

reverse in place with variable swapping (mutative)

```
const myArr = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
for (let i = 0; i < (myArr.length - 1) / 2; i++) {  
    const lastIndex = myArr.length - 1 - i; 
    [myArr[i], myArr[lastIndex]] = [myArr[lastIndex], myArr[i]] 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use swapping and return the original array.

```js
const reverseString = (s) => {
  let start = 0, end = s.length - 1;
  while (start < end) {
    [s[start], s[end]] = [s[end], s[start]]; // swap
    start++, end--;
  }
  return s;
};

console.log(reverseString(["s", "t", "r", "e", "s", "s", "e", "d"]));
```

Answer (score 2):

### Reverse by using the sort method

- This is a much more succinct method.

```js
const resultN = document.querySelector('.resultN');
const resultL = document.querySelector('.resultL');

const dataNum = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
const dataLetters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

const revBySort = (array) => array.sort((a, b) => a < b);

resultN.innerHTML = revBySort(dataNum);
resultL.innerHTML = revBySort(dataLetters);
```

```html
<div class="resultN"></div>
<div class="resultL"></div>
```

Comment: This in-place reversal isn’t efficient and the sort method is incorrect (an inconsistent comparison function has implementation-defined behaviour).

Comment: In addition to what Ry mentioned, this is an inefficient method considering in-place changes can be done in O(n/2), because you only need to really transverse half the array. Sort function's time complexity is O(n log n), which is worse than even an O(n) solution.

Answer (score 2):

Using ES6 rest operator and arrow function.

```
const reverse = ([x, ...s]) => x ? [...reverse(s), x] : [];
reverse([1,2,3,4,5]) //[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Infact the `reverse()` may not work in some cases, so you have to make an affectation first as the following

```
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
console.log(a);  // [1,2,3,4]
a = a.reverse();
console.log(a); // [4,3,2,1]
```

or use **concat**

```
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
console.log(a, a.concat([]).reverse());  // [1,2,3,4], [4,3,2,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

**What about without using push() !**

**Solution using XOR** !

```
var myARray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

function rver(x){
    var l = x.length;
    for(var i=0; i<Math.floor(l/2); i++){

        var a = x[i];
        var b = x[l-1-i];

        a = a^b;
        b = b^a;
        a = a^b;

        x[i] = a;
        x[l-1-i] = b;
    }

    return x;

}

console.log(rver(myARray));
```

Comment: What does this `^` symbol do in `a^b`?

Comment: Using temporary variables kind of defeats the point of an XOR swap.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript already has reverse() method on Array, so you don't need to do that much!

Imagine you have the array below:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

Now simply just do this:

```
arr.reverse();
```

and you get this as the result:

```
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
```

But this basically change the original array, you can write a function and use it to return a new array instead, something like this:

```
function reverse(arr) {
  var i = arr.length, reversed = [];
  while(i) {
    i--;
    reversed.push(arr[i]);
  }
  return reversed;
}
```

Or simply chaning JavaScript built-in methods for Array like this:

```
function reverse(arr) {
  return arr.slice().reverse();
}
```

and you can call it like this:

```
reverse(arr); //return [5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
```

Just as mentioned, the main difference is in the second way, you don't touch the original array...

Answer (score 0):

How about this?:

```
  function reverse(arr) {
    function doReverse(a, left, right) {
      if (left >= right) {
        return a;
      }
      const temp = a[left];
      a[left] = a[right];
      a[right] = temp;
      left++;
      right--;
      return doReverse(a, left, right);
    }

    return doReverse(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
  }

  console.log(reverse([1,2,3,4]));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ygpnt593/8/

Answer (score 0):

This function will work with arrays that may have gaps between their indices.

```
function reverse( a ) {
    var b = [], c = [] ;
    a.forEach( function( v ) { b.push( v ) } ) ;
    a.forEach( function( v, i ) { c[i] = b.pop() } ) ;
    return c ;
}

var a= [] ; a[1] = 2 ; a[3] = 4 ; a[7] = 6 ; a[9] = 8 ;
a = reverse( a ) ;
var s = '' ;
a.forEach( function( v, i ) { s += 'a[' + i + '] = ' + v + '  ' } ) ;
console.log( s ) ;
// a[1] = 8  a[3] = 6  a[7] = 4  a[9] = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

*Below is a solution with best space and time complexity*

```
function reverse(arr){
let i = 0;
let j = arr.length-1; 
while(i<j){
arr[j] = arr[j]+arr[i];
arr[i] = arr[j] - arr[i];
arr[j] = arr[j] - arr[i];
i++;
j--;
}
return arr;
}
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
reverse(arr);
```

**output => [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]**

Answer (score 0):

reverse array and sub-array (in place) with ES6.

```
function reverse(array, i=0, j=array.length-1){
  while (i < j){
    [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
    ++i;
    --j;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We have reverse() function to reverse the given array in JS.

```
var a = [7,8,9];
a.reverse(); // 9 8 7

function reverseArr(input) 
{
var ret = new Array;
for(var i = input.length-1; i >= 0; i--) 
{
    ret.push(input[i]);
}
return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem. Thank you for this question. I did the code like the below snippet. It works nicely. I used ES6.

```
const Array = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
let revArray = [].concat(Array).reverse();
```

when I console.log it I got the output like below

```
console.log(revArray)
// output: ["d","c","b","a"]
```

Comment: Why would you name your array `Array`? It is easily confused with keywords, and capitalising the first letter of a regular variable, while possible, it's against all conventions/best practices. Reserve that notion for signaling classes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
array.slice().reverse();
```

Leaves the original array unchanged. Works fine for primitive arrays. Careful with object arrays, as the new array will still reference the original objects.

Answer (score 0):

#### ES2023 Array Method [`toReversed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toReversed):

> The `toReversed()` method of [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) instances is the [`copying`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#copying_methods_and_mutating_methods) counterpart of the [`reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) method. It returns a new array with the elements in reversed order.

```js
const originalArray = [1, 2, 3];
const reversedArray  = originalArray.toReversed();
console.log(`Original Array ==> ${originalArray}`); //[1, 2, 3]
console.log(`Reversed Array ==> ${reversedArray}`); //[3, 2, 1]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

I just rewrote the haskell implementation to js.

```
const rev = (list, reversed) => {
    if (list.length == 0) return reversed

    reversed.unshift(list[0])
    return rev(list.slice(1), reversed)
}

const reverse = (list) => rev(list, [])
```

Comment: This implementation is seriously inefficient in JS, since arrays aren’t linked lists.