# how use javascript array

Tags: javascript

how use javascript

> reverse array

***i wanted it is***("861", "860","859","858" ............. )

```
    var arr = [
                "803", "812", "828", "846", "851",
                "852", "853", "857", "858", "859", "860", "861"
               ];
    var splitarr = arr.split(",");
     for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        console.log(splitarr);
     }
```

it is java arrays?

Comment: `arr` is an Array. Arrays don't have a `.split()` method. Also: [RTFM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse).

Comment: @George! thank you very much.. i get it is now..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I reverse an array in JavaScript without using libraries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168034/how-can-i-reverse-an-array-in-javascript-without-using-libraries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply: [**reverse()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)

> The reverse() method reverses an array in place. The first array
>   element becomes the last and the last becomes the first.

```
var arr = [
                "803", "812", "828", "846", "851",
                "852", "853", "857", "858", "859", "860", "861"
               ];
arr.reverse();
console.log(arr);
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s84z3nqL/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Array has a reverse function on it's prototype.

```
var arr = [
                "803", "812", "828", "846", "851",
                "852", "853", "857", "858", "859", "860", "861"
               ];
arr.reverse()
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse

Comment: updated to use your code

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call the reverse() function of javascript

```
arr.reverse();
```