# How create a foreach loop to print array in reverse?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, foreach

I need create a function that prints an array in reverse. The array is:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

My attempt is:

```
function printReverse(){
        for (i = array.length ; i >= 0;i--){
                console.log(array[i]);
        }
}
```

So i wonder if you can create the same think with foreach.
I could not find anything in the web about it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168034/how-can-i-reverse-an-array-in-javascript-without-using-libraries

Comment: you have an error here: i = array.length  change it to i = array.length - 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) will strictly 'enumerate' forward through the array, but the callback to `forEach` will be passed three arguments: the current item, the index of that item, and a reference to the original array. You can use the index to walk backwards from the end. For example:

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
array.forEach((_, i, a) => console.log(a[a.length - i - 1]));
```

Another trick is to use [`reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) to enumerate the items in reverse. The callback here will be passed an *accumulator* as the first argument (which you can simply ignore) and the item as the second argument. You'll have to pass in a value to initialize the accumulator as well, but again it doesn't really matter what that value is since you'll be ignoring it in this case:

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
array.reduceRight((_, x) => console.log(x), 0);
```

Comment: what "a" goes for in foreach i cant understend

Comment: @AlphaPigVLOG That's a reference to the original array. It would be equivalent to `array.forEach((_, i) => console.log(array[array.length - i - 1]));`.