# Log reverse an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to reverse an array in javascript. However each item has to be on a new line.

```
function logReverse(input) {
    let reverse = input.reverse();
    return reverse

}
// it does not log them all on different lines
logReverse(['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript'])
```

I need it to be returned like this IN MY CONSOLE **Each on a new line:

```
JAVASCRIPT
CSS
HTML

//NOT LIKE THIS 
[javascript,html,css]
```

Please help out

Comment: so join it with a line break.....

Comment: `function logReverse(input) { console.log(input.reverse().join("\n"); }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reverse an array in JavaScript without using libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168034/how-can-i-reverse-an-array-in-javascript-without-using-libraries)

Comment: @M.S. Mine is to get each on a new line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get this output:

```
JavaScript
CSS
HTML
```

Given the following input (Your array):

```
['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript']
```

You must, reverse the original array, then loop through it calling `console.log`.

Try the following function:

```
function logBackwards(arr) {
  // Reverse the input array
  const reversed = arr.reverse();

  // Log each item
  reversed.forEach((element) => {
    console.log(element);
  });
}

logBackwards(['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript']);
```

If you want to avoid using functions, a loop approach is also available.

```
function logBackwards(arr) {
  const lastItem = arr.length - 1;

  for (let i = lastItem; i >= 0; i--) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
  }
}

logBackwards(['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript']);
```

Hope it helps, good luck!

Answer (score 2):

To get that output, you need to either loop through the array and `console.log` each item:

```
logReverse(['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript']).forEach(e => console.log(e));
```

Or `join` into a string with a newline character as the delimiter.

```
console.log(logReverse(['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript']).join("\n"));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use Array.reverse()

```
var arr = logReverse(['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript']);
var new_arr = arr.reverse();
print(new_arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do this by appending a new line symbol to each string in your array

```
console.log(reversedArray.map(str => `${str}\n`))
```

Also, if you name a function "logReversed" than it means it should reverse and log. Otherwise, it's a bit confusing.

```
function logReverse(input) {
    console.log(input.reverse().map(str => `${str}\n`));
}
logReverse(['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript'])
```

Comment: Or just `input.reverse().join("\n")`

Answer (score 0):

Your function doesn't log anything, it returns the inverse so that you can do whatever you want to do with it, including logging it. You can use `join` to log each string in a separate line:

```js
function logReverse(input) {
    return input.reverse();
}

var rev = logReverse(['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript']);

console.log(rev.join('\n'));
```

Or, if you want the function to log it, just put the `console.log` code in it:

```js
function logReverse(input) {
    console.log(input.reverse().join('\n'));
}

logReverse(['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript']);
```